# Should multi tenant mean multiple instances?

Tags: sql-server, hosting, cloud, sql-server-2008-r2, multi-tenant

I want to share a SQL Server in a hosted environment, for Sharepoint and other software, using SQL Server.

Should I install one instance of SQL Server for each customer, or are there other options to consider?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about your hosted environment.  Is it a VPS?  Azure? (etc)

Comment: I use Windows Datacenter environment on ESX VMWare Server. Each customer will get a dedicated Windows Datacenter System with SPLA licence. All decicated servers will get a VLAN to the "shared" SQL server. I'm looking for a good way to share the SQL, for Sharepoint and maybe in future for other ECM/DMS Software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i install one instance on SQL Server for each customer

Yes, you can. With all the overhad and no sensible coordination.

> I want to share a SQL Server in an hosted environment

Do not provide sa / admin roles for tenants, but a UI that then creates databases, users etc.

Thousands of hosters do that, so you can too.

Higher editions of SQ LServer have a ressoruce governor that can avoid that one tenant swallows up the complete resources of a server.

Get used to by a real server with a lot of discs.

Comment: "not provide sa / admin roles for tenants, but a UI that then creates databases, users etc."
How to install the Sharepoint, in the FAQ from microsoft i sould use a Domain User to start the SQL Service Instance. Can i solve this issue?

Comment: YOu do not install sharepoint per user. Sharepoint ITSELF is multi tenant capable and has an API for managing that.

Comment: Yes i know that feature in theory, but out business model aims to use one Shapreoint Server VM for one customer. Just the SQL Database server should be for use with multiple tenants/customers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what resources you have available to you.

If all these applications are going to be using the same disk drive(s), then they will always be sharing physical media so putting them on different instances might not give you any real benefit.

I would recommend if possible to put different databases across different drives if you can, this will 'spread the load' of disk reading/writing between the applications.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install multiple instances of SQL Server (the number depends on edition, whether it's virtualized, etc) but this is not likely to be the way to go unless you have completely dedicated and isolated hardware for each instance. You probably want a *database* for each tenant, not an instance of SQL Server. At my previous job we had 500+ tenants happily co-existing on a single instance of SQL Server. With database separation this makes it easy to move a tenant to a different instance (or at least to different storage) should they start to eat away at performance.

Comment: Okay - i thought becouse auf security issues i wanted to use a new instance for each customer. Do you have a security guidline how to use one big Sharepoint Database for the multi tenants? Isn't there a limitation on DB space?

Comment: I don't know that I suggested everyone go in one big sharepoint database. I suggested that there is a middle ground - you can host multiple sharepoint and other databases on a single instance (or a small number of instances), instead of the extremes of a single database for all customers or an instance per customer.

Comment: there is nor problem for my hosting plan to give each customer an own instance. my only problem was hot to configure the SPFarm (Sharepoitn Admin User) for that database. in the normal setup installation the SQL and SP Serer are in the same ActiveDirectory Domain, but then the SQL Server would be in many Domains so the Domain User from sharepoint can start the windows sql server instance. how to solve this issue ??

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I don't administer sharepoint (never mind sharepoint farms). If each customer needs to be in their own domain, though, I think you've answered your own question. You can't have a single instance of SQL Server that lives in multiple domains.